# Hydroboration then oxidation with carbon monoxide and hydrogen peroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

[image: given question]

Thus is the question given in my textbook

[image: my working]
This is my attempt at the question [image: given solution]

This is the solution given in the textbook.

I don't understand how a ketone is formed instead of an acid. [related question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96262/hydroboration-oxidation-reaction-on-trans-trans-trans-1-5-9-cyclododecatriene-wi) This is a related question but in this a tertiary alcohol is formed instead of a ketone. What is the mechanism of formation if ketone and why is my mechanism wrong?

Answer (score 5):

There is a good explanation of the possible mechanisms of the ketone formation  [here](https://www.ch.ic.ac.uk/local/organic/tutorial/rzepa13/) which I have reproduced below. No pathway leads to an acid. Your mechanism has multiple CO insertions and only one occurs.

[image]

Comment: What if excess CO is used, even then only 1 insertion will take place?

Comment: Only one insertion will occur. As the reaction is run under an atmosphere of CO there will always be an excess present.